# Installing g++-dev on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, xserver, g++

when I try to install g++-dev on a newely installed Ubuntu 14.04, I get this error :

```
Les paquets suivants contiennent des dépendances non satisfaites :
 xserver-xorg-dev-lts-utopic : Est en conflit avec: xserver-xorg-dev
E: Impossible de corriger les problèmes, des paquets défectueux sont en mode « garder en l'état ».
```

can anyone help me to solve this ??

EDIT :

there is the output in english

```
$ LANG=C sudo apt-get install g++-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libcfg-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'lua5.1-lpeg-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libclang-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'packaging-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'librgxg-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libgtg-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libecpg-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'xserver-xorg-dev-lts-saucy' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libghc-hxt-relaxng-dev-9.1.4-6441f' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libghc-blaze-svg-dev-0.3.3.0-91cb1' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'erlang-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libini-config-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libcpg-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'liblua5.1-lpeg-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libsyslog-ng-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'dpkg-dev-el' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libfontconfig-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'syslog-ng-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'eog-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libaudid3tag-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'shhmsg-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libghc-bytestring-lexing-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libdballe-msg-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libunistring-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'liboce-modeling-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libghc-boomerang-dev-1.4.0-3f832' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libghc-bytestring-dev-0.10.0.2-0b661' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'lua5.1-rex-onig-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libghc-asn1-encoding-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libopencascade-modeling-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libogg-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libthepeg-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libhdf4g-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libmodplug-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libghc-web-routes-boomerang-dev-0.28.0-6f82d' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libpam0g-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'happycoders-libdbg-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libsmpeg-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libghc-dpkg-dev-0.0.3-ba83c' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libghc-base64-bytestring-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libevtlog-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'mesag-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libnetfilter-log-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libghc-pipes-bytestring-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'golang-goget-ubuntu-touch-bootimg-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'xserver-xorg-dev-lts-quantal' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libghc-ekg-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libopencsg-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libcolorhug-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'xserver-xorg-dev-lts-utopic' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'gpointing-device-settings' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libwxsvg-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'dpkg-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libdialog-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libdshconfig-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libconfig-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libghc-hxt-relaxng-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libming-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'med-imaging-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libradiusclient-ng-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libgengameng-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libm17n-im-config-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'librlog-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libglobus-gsi-sysconfig-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'xorg-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libghc-pipes-bytestring-dev-2.0.0-a203a' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libsamba-hostconfig-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libcableswig-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'ntfs-3g-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'openoffice.org-dev-doc' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libtk-img-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libghc-utf8-string-dev-0.3.7-b85cc' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libgnome-keyring-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'lua5.2-rex-onig-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'liblockdev0g-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-cg-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'liburg-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'golang-go-xdg-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libtotem-pg-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libjpeg-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'xserver-xorg-dev-lts-raring' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libpaperg-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libghc-dpkg-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libfirestring-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libaqbanking-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libplayerjpeg-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libopenjpeg-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libghc-web-routes-boomerang-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libboost-log-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libghc-blaze-svg-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'liblua5.1-leg-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libmng-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libcap-ng-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libipmimonitoring-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libopencv-stitching-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'lua-lpeg-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libghc-asn1-encoding-dev-0.8.1.1-10067' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libxmltooling-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libghc-bytestring-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libcanna1g-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libncarg-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libwpg-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'zlib1g-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'lua5.2-lpeg-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libwebrtc-audio-processing-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libbiosig-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libroot-montecarlo-eg-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libdpkg-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libghc-utf8-string-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'liboping-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libspctag-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libapt-pkg-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libgig-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'liblangtag-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libghc-bytestring-lexing-dev-0.4.3-436a2' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libchewing-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libeditorconfig-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libpolyclipping-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libghc-ekg-dev-0.3.1.3-b8023' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libadplug-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'cimg-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libghc-boomerang-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libghc-diagrams-svg-dev-0.8.0.2-883bb' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libbg-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libonig-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'science-engineering-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libvdeplug-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'lua-rex-onig-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'slang-dev6' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'xserver-xorg-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'octave-pkg-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libghc-unix-bytestring-dev-0.3.5.4-503dc' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'lua5.1-leg-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libdogleg-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libghc-diagrams-svg-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libghc-base16-bytestring-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libghc-unix-bytestring-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libghc-base64-bytestring-dev-1.0.0.1-a619b' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libgoogle-glog-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libjbig-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libghc-generic-deriving-dev-1.4.0-94eaa' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libopenmeeg-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libshhmsg-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libsynfig-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'xviewg-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libghc-base16-bytestring-dev-0.1.1.5-a277b' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libagg-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'xserver-xorg-dev-lts-trusty' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libghc-generic-deriving-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'xaw3dg-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libusbprog-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'lua-leg-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libzerg-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libpng-dev' for regex 'g++-dev'
Note, selecting 'libpng12-dev' instead of 'libpng-dev'
Note, selecting 'dialog' instead of 'libdialog-dev'
Note, selecting 'libfontconfig1-dev' instead of 'libfontconfig-dev'
Note, selecting 'libpaper-dev' instead of 'libpaperg-dev'
Note, selecting 'audacious-dev' instead of 'libaudid3tag-dev'
Note, selecting 'ghc' instead of 'libghc-bytestring-dev'
Note, selecting 'ghc' instead of 'libghc-bytestring-dev-0.10.0.2-0b661'
Note, selecting 'libaqbanking34-dev' instead of 'libaqbanking-dev'
Note, selecting 'libbg1-dev' instead of 'libbg-dev'
Note, selecting 'libdshconfig1-dev' instead of 'libdshconfig-dev'
Note, selecting 'libghc-asn1-encoding-dev' instead of 'libghc-asn1-encoding-dev-0.8.1.1-10067'
Note, selecting 'libghc-base64-bytestring-dev' instead of 'libghc-base64-bytestring-dev-1.0.0.1-a619b'
Note, selecting 'libghc-base16-bytestring-dev' instead of 'libghc-base16-bytestring-dev-0.1.1.5-a277b'
Note, selecting 'libghc-blaze-svg-dev' instead of 'libghc-blaze-svg-dev-0.3.3.0-91cb1'
Note, selecting 'libghc-boomerang-dev' instead of 'libghc-boomerang-dev-1.4.0-3f832'
Note, selecting 'libghc-bytestring-lexing-dev' instead of 'libghc-bytestring-lexing-dev-0.4.3-436a2'
Note, selecting 'libghc-utf8-string-dev' instead of 'libghc-utf8-string-dev-0.3.7-b85cc'
Note, selecting 'libghc-diagrams-svg-dev' instead of 'libghc-diagrams-svg-dev-0.8.0.2-883bb'
Note, selecting 'libghc-dpkg-dev' instead of 'libghc-dpkg-dev-0.0.3-ba83c'
Note, selecting 'libghc-ekg-dev' instead of 'libghc-ekg-dev-0.3.1.3-b8023'
Note, selecting 'libghc-generic-deriving-dev' instead of 'libghc-generic-deriving-dev-1.4.0-94eaa'
Note, selecting 'libghc-hxt-relaxng-dev' instead of 'libghc-hxt-relaxng-dev-9.1.4-6441f'
Note, selecting 'libghc-pipes-bytestring-dev' instead of 'libghc-pipes-bytestring-dev-2.0.0-a203a'
Note, selecting 'libghc-unix-bytestring-dev' instead of 'libghc-unix-bytestring-dev-0.3.5.4-503dc'
Note, selecting 'libghc-web-routes-boomerang-dev' instead of 'libghc-web-routes-boomerang-dev-0.28.0-6f82d'
Note, selecting 'syslog-ng-core' instead of 'libsyslog-ng-dev'
Note, selecting 'libplayerjpeg3.0-dev' instead of 'libplayerjpeg-dev'
Note, selecting 'libshhmsg1-dev' instead of 'libshhmsg-dev'
Note, selecting 'liburg0-dev' instead of 'liburg-dev'
Note, selecting 'libzerg0-dev' instead of 'libzerg-dev'
Note, selecting 'lua-leg-dev' instead of 'liblua5.1-leg-dev'
Note, selecting 'lua-leg-dev' instead of 'lua5.1-leg-dev'
Note, selecting 'lua-lpeg-dev' instead of 'liblua5.1-lpeg-dev'
Note, selecting 'lua-lpeg-dev' instead of 'lua5.1-lpeg-dev'
Note, selecting 'lua-lpeg-dev' instead of 'lua5.2-lpeg-dev'
Note, selecting 'lua-rex-onig-dev' instead of 'lua5.1-rex-onig-dev'
Note, selecting 'lua-rex-onig-dev' instead of 'lua5.2-rex-onig-dev'
dialog is already the newest version.
zlib1g-dev is already the newest version.
zlib1g-dev set to manually installed.
dpkg-dev is already the newest version.
xserver-xorg-dev-lts-utopic is already the newest version.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xserver-xorg-dev-lts-utopic : Conflicts: xserver-xorg-dev
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
myuser@myserver:~$`
```

Comment: Please can you translate the error into english?

Comment: There seem to be at least two issues here: first, AFAIK there is no package called `g++-dev`: because of that, `apt-get` may be trying to treat it as a regular expression and attempting to install all kinds of other spurious packages. Second, you appear to have enabled a repository from Utopic (14.10) in your sources.

Comment: You can get English command output by writing `LANG=C mycommand --myarguments etc...`. The **LANG=C** prefix sets the language to your default fallback (usually English) for this single command following it. So you would have to type something like `LANG=C sudo apt-get install g++-dev`. And please also include the command you typed in.

Comment: I added an edit for english output

Comment: What I understand from the error is : the package that I want to install (g++-dev) depends on two other packages which are : xserver-xorg-dev-lts-utopic and xserver-xorg-dev , those two packages are in conflict which means that they can not be installed in the same machine, 
So how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Do you have trusty -proposed enabled? & if so, have you upgraded to the lts-utopic mesa packages? this will show - `apt-cache policy  xserver-xorg-dev*` look for which one is installed

Comment: I didn't understand the two first questions, the command `apt-cache policy xserver-xorg-dev*`  shows that I do not have any package installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There is no such package.](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/g++-dev) As the output indicates, `apt` then tried to match for the regex `g++-dev`, that is, any package whose name contains `g-dev`. For the `g++` compiler, use the `g++` package, and for the C++ standard libraries, use one of the `libstdc++-dev` packages, like [`libstdc++-4.8-dev`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libstdc++-4.8-dev).